# why does PHP allow creating class properties from outside the class?

Tags: php, properties

Coming from a Java background, I find this odd. Please have a look at this code -

```
<?php  
    class People {
        private $name;
        private $age;
        public function set_info($name, $age) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = $age;
        }

        public function get_info() {
            echo "Name : {$this->name}<br />";
            echo "Age : {$this->age}<br />";
        }
    }

    $p1 = new People();
    $p1->set_info("Sam",22);
    $p1->get_info();

    $p1->ID = 12057;

    echo "<pre>".print_r($p1,true)."</pre>";
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
People Object
(
    [name:People:private] => Sam
    [age:People:private] => 22
    [ID] => 12057
)
```

Having not created any property as `ID` in the `People` class, yet I can assign a value to `ID` outside the class using `p1`.

In Java, this would give an error -

> cannot find symbol

Is this a feature in PHP? If it is then what is it called? And how is it beneficial?

Comment: Yes, this is a feature of PHP's objects. I think you should not rely on it. My opinion is it is for retrocompatibility with PHP4's object model (which looked like arrays with methods). I could not find any official documentation about this.

Comment: Here's a way to avoid it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9136464/472495

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132970/undefined-public-member-variables-getting-initialized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since PHP is a dynamically typed scripting language it allows for `Dynamic Properties`. I refer you to this [this article](http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass).

> Languages like JavaScript and Python allow object instances to have
>   dynamic properties. As it turns out, PHP does too. Looking at the
>   official PHP documentation on objects and classes you might be lead to
>   believe dynamic instance properties require custom __get and __set
>   magic methods. They don't.